# rsync doesn't work, but ssh and scp do

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, rsync, scp

I am trying to copy files from a remote server (linux) to my client (osx) using

```
rsync -avz remote:/path/to/file .
```

but the connection hangs and the transfer is never completed. Instead, I can successfully `scp` and `ssh`. The configuration I am using is

```
ServerAliveInterval 120

Host            *
ForwardX11       yes

Host            remote
HostName        remote.address.uk
HostKeyAlias    remote.address.uk
User            myusername
LocalForward    localhost:5903 remote:5904
LocalForward    localhost:5902 remote:5901
TCPKeepAlive    yes
IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If I understand correctly the default port for `rsync` is the same as for `ssh` and `scp`. How can I make `rsync` work again?

I have got the following output from running `rsync -e "ssh -v" -avz remote:~/file .`

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/.ssh/config line 3: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/.ssh/config line 41: Applying options for remote
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to remote.address.uk [129.234.196.8] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: using hostkeyalias: remote.address.uk
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 43:2b:c5:8c:c4:fc:c3:9a:eb:0d:92:58:63:9a:56:00
debug1: using hostkeyalias: remote.address.uk
debug1: Host 'remote.address.uk' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to remote.address.uk ([129.234.196.8]:22).
debug1: Local connections to localhost:5903 forwarded to remote address remote:5904
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 5903.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 5903.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Local connections to localhost:5902 forwarded to remote address remote:5901
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 5902.
debug1: channel 2: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 5902.
debug1: channel 3: new [port listener]
debug1: channel 4: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
```

EDIT:

now `ssh` also hangs after `Entering interactive session`, but `ssh -fN remote` still works. 
I have tried removing `.bash*` `.profile` `.cshrc` on the server side, with no result. The ssh connection to another remote server that is available to me also fails.

I have found that this problem  only happens on my `osx` client. I have found that `rsync` and `ssh` work for both remote servers on my `Linux` box that I run on a virtual box on `osx`.

Comment: and `sftp` works?

Comment: how do I check this?

Comment: run `sftp remote`

Comment: yes, indeed it works.

Comment: What happens if you explicitly run rsync over ssh (with `rsync -e ssh`)?

Comment: this also hangs

Comment: For rsync to work, doesn't it have to be installed on both computers?  SSH is just the means (one of the means?) to communicate to the remote computer, but the remote needs to be able to run "something" to communicate over that SSH.  I've always assumed that you need rsync (or rsyncd) on the remote end.

Comment: it is installed both on the server and on the client

Comment: Try running ssh in verbose mode (`rsync -e "ssh -v"`), and see if that prints anything informative.

Comment: I have tried this already, but what should I look for?

Comment: Maybe it is copying a really large file:  What happens if you wait a few minutes?

Comment: no, the file is very small. I created it for this purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that xquartz on my `osx` is broken for some reason. Hence, X forwarding doesn't work. I have disabled X forwarding and now I can connect

#### How to disable X forwarding (for osx)

1. Edit ~/.ssh/config
2. Add/uncomment `ForwardX11 no`

["how to" source](https://robert.accettura.com/blog/2012/05/16/disable-x11-when-using-ssh-on-mac-os-x/)